Unconsistent display of unicode chars between software and Ubuntus
I have two computers installed slightly differently :

A: KUbuntu based on 22.04.3 LTS
B: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS + KDE somehow added after

I noticed between the 2 that some (not all) Unicode chars where displayed differently when appearing inside JetBrains Intellij Idea (either in source files or console tool window). I suspected IJ to be the source of the problem until i noticed that differences were beyond that.
Let's consider two chars that behave differently:

U+2705 "White Heavy Check Mark" ✅  (should be displayed as a white check inside a green square)
U+1F9E1 "Orange heart"  (displayed in orange...)

On computer A, no issue. Both chars are displayed with green/orange colors everywhere (idea, zsh/bash console, sublime text document, location bar or file names in Dolphin).
On computer B,

orange heart is

a correct orange heart in shells, sublime or IJ
an empty square inside dolphin


the check is

a green check in shells
a bad looking green check on a white background in IJ, or dolphin filenames when created from outside dolphin
an empty square inside dolphin location bar, or filenames when created from dolphin



Maybe it's basic and a simple installation could fix it but i don't know a lot in this area and i'm confused as on a given computer, the same char can be displayed differently.
To be noted that both IJs are configure to use the internal font JetBrains Mono.
When using "Font management" and changing the displayed sample text, none of the fonts is able to display the colors (and only one in black&white...), on both computers :(
So how can i find which font is used to display which character so that i can install what's missing, or change whatever is needed to solve the issue ?
Thanks,
P.

just a small remark: the shell is completely uninvolved in displaying anything; you mean the terminal emulator (which might be gnome-shell, or konsole, or something else)

I'm a bit less surprised than you: This Y looks different when I write "Y", "Y", "Y" or "Y", because all three use different type faces. Same for unicode codes from non-letter codepages: it's down to the font and the font rendering engine to render them to your screen.
